# Homogeneous system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following set of equations with 4 unknowns $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and constant coefficients $A,B,C,E$

$\begin{align}
(A-E)x_1 + B x_2 - C x_3 = 0
\\
B x_1 - (A+E)x_2 - C x_4 = 0
\\
C x_1 - (A+E)x_3 - Bx_4 = 0
\\
C x_2 - Bx_3 + (A-E)x_4 = 0
\end{align}$

The determinant of the matrix from which I obtain these equations must be zero (this is a constraint).

I am trying to find expressions for $x_i$. Since the family of equations is homogeneous, there are an infinite amount of solutions, so I set $x_4 = 1$ arbitrarily. I proceeded as follows: I take the last equation (for example) and express $x_2$ in terms of $x_3$, substitute my answer into the first equation to obtain an expression of $x_1$ in terms of $x_3$, and then use this result in the third equation to obtain an expression solely in terms of $x_3$.

However, I just end up with $0 = 0$ no matter how I rearrange or substitute the terms. What am I missing?

Comment: What makes you think that there is an infinite amount of solutions? Setting up a matrix representing your problem, we see that in most cases the determinant will be nonzero, i.e., there will only be the trivial solution.

Comment: It's actually a physics problem and there is a constraint on the matrix from which I obtained these equations that its determinant must be zero. Sorry, I should have specified that.

Comment: Hint: What if you tried doing row reduced echelon form? You would end up with the identity matrix. What is this telling you? This is also a special matrix in that it is symmetric and circulant (maybe others too).

Comment: If the row-reduced echelon form results in the identity matrix, then all the unknowns are equal to zero and only the trivial solution exists?

Comment: @Calavera: If you do not get the identity matrix, then either $A^{-1}$ does not exist or there is not a unique solution to the linear system $Ax=b$. So, your system has a unique solution.